kxcjk1013 accelerometer driver uses identity matrix despite hwdb and udev rules defining the correct mount matrix
I am using a Teclast F6 Pro 2-in-1 Laptop with two kxcjk1013 accelerometers which is used for screen orientation and tablet mode toggling.
While the sensor seems to be functional (e.g., I can read acceleration values using cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device*/in_accel_*_raw, ix X11 the screen orientation is respoding when I rotate the monitor), the orientation reported by the driver is incorrect. This prevents the tablet mode activation, since the two sensor are never seen in the correct orientation relative to each other.

Specifically, I see the following message in dmesg:
kxcjk1013 i2c-KIOX020A:00: mounting matrix not found: using identity...
kxcjk1013 i2c-KIOX010A:00: mounting matrix not found: using identity...

From the kxcjk1013 driver source code, I understand this happens when the driver fails to find a mount matrix in ACPI, sysfs, or device properties.
The driver will try to get the properties first from platform data, if that fails, then from ACPI, if that fails then from IIO and if that fails, then it will resort to the identity matrix, which is what is happening here.
Code snippets
kxcjk1013_get_mount_matrix
static const struct iio_mount_matrix *
kxcjk1013_get_mount_matrix(const struct iio_dev *indio_dev,
               const struct iio_chan_spec *chan)
{
    struct kxcjk1013_data *data = iio_priv(indio_dev);

    return &data->orientation;
}

kxcjk1013_probe
    pdata = dev_get_platdata(&client->dev);
    if (pdata) {
        data->active_high_intr = pdata->active_high_intr;
        data->orientation = pdata->orientation;
    } else {
        data->active_high_intr = true; /* default polarity */

        if (!iio_read_acpi_mount_matrix(&client->dev, &data->orientation, "ROTM")) {
            ret = iio_read_mount_matrix(&client->dev, &data->orientation);
            if (ret)
                return ret;
        }

    }

ACPI Method (if dev_get_platdata fails)
/**
 * iio_read_acpi_mount_matrix() - Read accelerometer mount matrix info from ACPI
 * @dev:        Device structure
 * @orientation:    iio_mount_matrix struct to fill
 * @acpi_method:    ACPI method name to read the matrix from, usually "ROTM"
 *
 * Try to read the mount-matrix by calling the specified method on the device's
 * ACPI firmware-node. If the device has no ACPI firmware-node; or the method
 * does not exist then this will fail silently. This expects the method to
 * return data in the ACPI "ROTM" format defined by Microsoft:
 * https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/sensors/sensors-acpi-entries
 * This is a Microsoft extension and not part of the official ACPI spec.
 * The method name is configurable because some dual-accel setups define 2 mount
 * matrices in a single ACPI device using separate "ROMK" and "ROMS" methods.
 *
 * Returns: true if the matrix was successfully, false otherwise.
 */
bool iio_read_acpi_mount_matrix(struct device *dev,
                struct iio_mount_matrix *orientation,
                char *acpi_method)
{
    struct acpi_buffer buffer = { ACPI_ALLOCATE_BUFFER, NULL };
    char *str;
    union acpi_object *obj, *elements;
    acpi_handle handle;
    acpi_status status;
    int i, j, val[3];
    bool ret = false;

    handle = ACPI_HANDLE(dev);
    if (!handle)
        return false;

    if (!acpi_has_method(handle, acpi_method))
        return false;

    status = acpi_evaluate_object(handle, acpi_method, NULL, &buffer);
    if (ACPI_FAILURE(status)) {
        dev_err(dev, "Failed to get ACPI mount matrix: %d\n", status);
        return false;
    }

    obj = buffer.pointer;
    if (obj->type != ACPI_TYPE_PACKAGE || obj->package.count != 3) {
        dev_err(dev, "Unknown ACPI mount matrix package format\n");
        goto out_free_buffer;
    }

    elements = obj->package.elements;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (elements[i].type != ACPI_TYPE_STRING) {
            dev_err(dev, "Unknown ACPI mount matrix element format\n");
            goto out_free_buffer;
        }

        str = elements[i].string.pointer;
        if (sscanf(str, "%d %d %d", &val[0], &val[1], &val[2]) != 3) {
            dev_err(dev, "Incorrect ACPI mount matrix string format\n");
            goto out_free_buffer;
        }

        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            switch (val[j]) {
            case -1: str = "-1"; break;
            case 0:  str = "0";  break;
            case 1:  str = "1";  break;
            default:
                dev_err(dev, "Invalid value in ACPI mount matrix: %d\n", val[j]);
                goto out_free_buffer;
            }
            orientation->rotation[i * 3 + j] = str;
        }
    }

    ret = true;

out_free_buffer:
    kfree(buffer.pointer);
    return ret;
}

iio Method (if ACPI fails)
/**
 * iio_read_mount_matrix() - retrieve iio device mounting matrix from
 *                           device "mount-matrix" property
 * @dev:    device the mounting matrix property is assigned to
 * @matrix: where to store retrieved matrix
 *
 * If device is assigned no mounting matrix property, a default 3x3 identity
 * matrix will be filled in.
 *
 * Returns: 0 if success, or a negative error code on failure.
 */
int iio_read_mount_matrix(struct device *dev, struct iio_mount_matrix *matrix)
{
    size_t len = ARRAY_SIZE(iio_mount_idmatrix.rotation);
    int err;

    err = device_property_read_string_array(dev, "mount-matrix", matrix->rotation, len);
    if (err == len)
        return 0;

    if (err >= 0)
        /* Invalid number of matrix entries. */
        return -EINVAL;

    if (err != -EINVAL)
        /* Invalid matrix declaration format. */
        return err;

    /* Matrix was not declared at all: fallback to identity. */
    return iio_setup_mount_idmatrix(dev, matrix);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(iio_read_mount_matrix);

Identity matrix fallback (if iio fails)
static int iio_setup_mount_idmatrix(const struct device *dev,
                    struct iio_mount_matrix *matrix)
{
    *matrix = iio_mount_idmatrix;
    dev_info(dev, "mounting matrix not found: using identity...\n");
    return 0;
}

Read device property
int device_property_read_string_array(const struct device *dev, const char *propname,
                      const char **val, size_t nval)
{
    return fwnode_property_read_string_array(dev_fwnode(dev), propname, val, nval);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(device_property_read_string_array);

It seems like retreiving the mount matrix from both ACPI and Sysfs fails.
iio_read_acpi_mount_matrix
err = device_property_read_string_array(dev, "mount-matrix", matrix->rotation, len); does not work as expected given the input it receives, since it uses fallback to identity matrix in iio_read_mount_matrix. It uses matrix-mount as a propname, while the property in the device is called in_accel_mount_matrix or ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX.

Here are the key points of my setup and observations:

Driver Behavior:

The driver seems to expect a mount-matrix property either via ACPI or sysfs.
However, in I only see cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0/, the attribute exists as in_accel_mount_matrix, not mount-matrix.
Is this a naming mismatch? Does the driver translate between in_accel_mount_matrix and mount-matrix?


ACPI Details:

The device is detected via ACPI, but no mount matrix is defined here (/sys/bus/acpi/devices/KIOX010A:00/).
The DRIVER attribute for the ACPI device is empty. Can I apply udev rules for ACPI devices to address this? Does ACPI use a separate driver or should I expect the driver linked above to be referenced here?
I decompiled the ACPI Tables (DSDT) and found the devices here, but there is no mount matrix defined here. Can I retroactively define it?
The ACPI device for the accelerometer is present (/sys/bus/acpi/devices/KIOX010A:00/), but there’s no driver associated with it (DRIVER=="").
Could this lack of a driver cause the mount matrix from ACPI to be ignored?


udev Rules and hwdb:

The mount matrix is defined correctly via 60-sensor.hwdb:
## Teclast F6 Pro (2 sensors)
sensor:modalias:acpi:KIOX010A*:dmi:*:svnTECLAST:pnF6Pro:*
ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX=-1, 0, 0; 0, -1, 0; 0, 0, -1
ACCEL_LOCATION=display

sensor:modalias:acpi:KIOX020A*:dmi:*:svnTECLAST:pnF6Pro:*
ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX=0, 1, 0; 1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1
ACCEL_LOCATION=base


I've defined it additionally via udev rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-i2c-sensor.rules, as follows:
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="iio:device0", ATTR{in_accel_mount_matrix}="0, 1, 0; 1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1"
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="iio:device1", ATTR{in_accel_mount_matrix}="-1, 0, 0; 0, -1, 0; 0, 0, -1"


However, these don’t seem to affect the driver's behavior. The correct matrix does not seem to be picked up.




Question:
Driver:

Is the naming mismatch between mount-matrix (in kernel driver) and in_accel_mount_matrix (in device properties) the likely cause of the problem? If so, how can I resolve it?
Is the format of the mount matrix (comma, semicolon separated) what the driver is expecting?
How can I further debug the kernel behaviour and why it is not able to read the mount matrix? Either by replicating the kernel behaviour on a separate script or by modifying and compiling the kernel itself.

Device properties and configuration

Why are hwdb and udev rules not working? Is it an issue of the driver not looking here, of an issue of the data provided to the driver not being as expected?
Can I manually edit the platform data so it can be read here?
Can I add udev rules for ACPI or I2C, analogously to how I did it for IIO?
If the matrix is defined in the hwdb for ACPI, why is it not showing as an attribute for the device?
Are there any additional debugging steps or alternatives I can try (e.g., creating a custom Device Tree overlay, kernel patches, or other methods)?

Any advice or suggestions on how to make the kxcjk1013 driver pick up the correct mount matrix would be greatly appreciated!

Let me know if you’d like further refinements to the question.
